# Grammar construction "subject + to + infinitive" question

Tags: grammar

1. The sentence:
   The youngest sailor to complete the voyage unassisted is another Australian, Jesse Martin, who was 18 when he completed it in 1999.
2. The question:
   How should I understand the construction " The youngest sailor to complete "?
   If here "to complete..." expresses "finished action" and it means smth like "who completed..." explain, pls, that grammar construction.

Comment: The first user to answer was FumbleFingers (albeit only in a comment). It's a common alternative to *the first X **who did** something*.

Comment: I'd analyse "The youngest sailor to complete the voyage unassisted" as a noun phrase, in which "to complete the voyage unassisted" is an infinitival relative clause modifying "sailor": "The youngest sailor [ __ to complete the voyage unassisted], where gap is subject.

Answer (score 6):

The infinitival (*to V<sup>INF</sup>PHRASE*) in this construction is licensed by the superlative adjective *youngest*; it expresses the domain to which the superlative applies. Just about any superlative can enter into this construction, and the superlative can be 'fused' with its head noun (the noun it modifies) if that head is obvious from context:

> The youngest <s>sailor</s> to complete the voyage . . .
>   The most famous <s>sailor</s> to complete the voyage . . .

As you speculate, it may be paraphrased as a relative clause, and as a matter of style probably should be paraphrased if the superlative is an adverb 'transferred' to the subject of the infinitival:

> <sup>awkward</sup> The most recent sailor to complete the voyage . . .
>   <sup>better</sup> The sailor who *most recently* completed the voyage . . .

Comment: It's only awkward with *most recent*. Nothing at all awkward about *The **last** person to arrive was John*, which works fine in many contexts where *The last person **who arrived** was John* might be a little "odd".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, you're right; same thing applies to *first*, *second*, etc. My criterion is clearly inadequate. How then could we distinguish cases like *most recent*, *swiftest*?

Comment: I'd analyse "to complete the voyage unassisted" as an infinitival relative clause modifying "sailor": "The youngest sailor [ __ to complete the voyage unassisted], where gap is subject.

Comment: Why is **The most recent strain of flu to hit the region was X** preferred over **The most recent strain of flu hitting the region was X** ? (though best is **The strain of flu to hit the region most recently was X**).

Comment: @BillJ But doesn't it really 'modify'--restrict the sense of--*youngest*? Without the adjective the infinitival is indeed a relative but has a prospective sense; here it has a retrospective sense; with an absolute or comparative it's ambiguous (but evident from context). I suggest that this is a distinct construction in which *-est .. to* is analogous to *-er .. than*

Answer (score 1):

The sentence: The youngest sailor **to complete the voyage unassisted** is another Australian, Jesse Martin, who was 18 when he completed it in 1999.

**I would edit this as follows**:

The sentence: The youngest sailor to **have completed the voyage** unassisted is another Australian, Jesse Martin, who was 18 when he completed it in 1999.

Why? Because X to Y [present infinitive] doesn't really fit here in the same way that it would not fit in the examples below.

- The boy to do the job is Paul. [a general statement; job not yet done]

  COMPARE: The boy to have done the job is Paul.
- The man to see about this problem is Mike. [problem not yet seen to]

  COMPARE: The man to have seen about this problem is Mike.
- The youngest sailor to compete in the race is John. [competition not yet held]

  COMPARE: The youngest sailor to have competed in the race is John.

**Past Tense**:
- The  youngest sailor to **have competed in the race** is [or was] John.

To me, the "youngest sailor to complete" is understandable but not right. Because **the race is over**, though John remains John. Or the speaker can decide to use the past: was John.

**Since the race is over, I feel that the to followed by the infinitive requires a past tense**.

And the adjective really changes nothing in terms of what is past and what isn't past. You can add or remove adjectives in the sentences above and it will not govern the sentence, one way or the other.

I use the term "tense" here loosely: the point is that "to have completed the voyage" it not "to complete the voyage" and any good English-language editor would correct it. Please see the examples I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your question about "finished action", consider the following sentences, all of which have an infinitival following a noun-phrase.  I don't think these infinitives express completion unless there's a perfect ("to have struck", "to have reached").

> The way to go is by train.
>
> The movie to see is Jurassic Park.
>
> It was the worst storm to have struck the region in forty years.
>
> At 103, he is the oldest man ever to attempt the summit.
>
> At 103, he was the oldest man ever to attempt the summit.
>
> At 103, he was the oldest man ever to have reached the summit.
>
> At 103, he is the oldest man ever to have reached the summit.
>
> The thing not to do is panic.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I said.

Answer (score 1):

> *The youngest sailor to complete the voyage unassisted is another*
>   *Australian ...*

You are right. The sentence is equivalent simply to *the youngest sailor who completed the voyage unassisted ...*

Nominals containing relative clauses with this kind of interpretation usually contain a modifier such as "only", "next", "last", or one of the ordinal numbers "first", "second" etc. Here the modifier is the adjective "youngest".

Here is a simplified tree diagram:

[image]

Comment: How can "The  youngest sailor to complete the voyage" be equivalent "who  completed [past tense] the voyage". One is present, the other past.

Comment: Isn't the suplerlative etc a red herring here?  *Every sailor but one needed help finishing the voyage. The sailor to complete the voyage unassisted was an Aussie...*   (**unassisted**  does the work of **only** in context).

Comment: @Lambie The VP "to complete the voyage" is an infintival clause with a plain form verb, **not** present tense.

Comment: @BillJ Again, call it what you like, it is a fact that ***the  youngest sailor to have completed the voyage*** is not ***the youngest sailor to complete the voyage***. To complete the voyage here is a mistake and any good English-language editor would correct when copy editing. And I do not believe I used the word **tense** did I? I specifically did not use that word, in fact.

Comment: There is most very definitely a time issue in this type of utterance.

Comment: @Lambie What are you talking about? I made no mention of "to have completed the voyage". And the infinitival "the youngest sailor to complete the voyage" is not a mistake - it's fine.

Comment: @BillJ I am saying that this utterance in this context cannot be analyzed without comparing it to: to have completed. If you deign to look at the examples I generated, you will see why that is. So, it wasn't you who mentioned it, it was me (I, if you prefer). And I consider it a contextual sine qua non here. :).

Comment: "The  youngest sailor who complet**ed** the voyage" is equivalent to "The youngest sailor to have completed the voyage". Even you, in the first line of your answer put in complet**ed). Yes, the past is there, isn't it? You said: "The sentence is equivalent simply to the youngest sailor who completed the voyage unassisted ..."  Isn't that a past idea?

Comment: @Lambie Semantically, since the event is in the past, i.e. complete, it's OK to paraphrase in the past tense. Infinitival clauses typically have a modal interpretation, but not here. That's why it can be useful to point out the non-modal meaning of the OP's example.

Comment: @BillJ Please see this paper: tensed 3-2 Tensed infinitive Clauses: A Semantic Viewpoint:Stowell (1982:562) argues that infinitive clauses, functioning as verb complementation, **do convey tense; and that such clauses have the feature of tenses**. I rest my case.

Comment: The infinitival clause in the OP's example is not functioning as a complement of any verb, but as modifier of the noun "sailor", i.e. it is a relative clause.

Comment: Ok, could you write this sentence, the first part using another words with maximum conformity ?